# How to force re-sort jsTree?

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

How to force a tree re-sort ?
I have added the menu to change sort order ASC/DESC:

```
"Sort": {
    "separator_before": false,
    "separator_after": true,
    "label": "Sort",
    "action": false,
    "submenu": {
        "Ascending": {
            "seperator_before": false,
            "seperator_after": false,
            "label": "Ascending",
            action: function (obj) {
                setSortFunction('asc');
                var selector = '#treeview';
                var root = $(selector).jstree(true).get_node("1");//get_node("root");
                $(selector).jstree(true).sort(root, true);
                $(selector).jstree(true).redraw_node(root, true);
            }
        },
        "Descending": {
            "seperator_before": false,
            "seperator_after": false,
            "label": "Descending",
            action: function (obj) {
                setSortFunction('desc');
                var selector = '#treeview';
                var root = $(selector).jstree(true).get_node("1");//get_node("root");
                $(selector).jstree(true).sort(root, true);
                $(selector).jstree(true).redraw_node(root, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

It changes the asc/desc order but I need re-sorte the existing tree using the new order. I have tried to do as in code above but it does not work.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sortType = "asc";



$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#test").on("changed.jstree", function(e, data) {

  }).jstree({
    plugins: ['checkbox',  'changed', 'contextmenu', 'sort'],
    contextmenu: {
      select_node: false,
      items: contextMenu
    },
    checkbox: {
      three_state: false
    },
    sort : function(a, b) {
        a1 = this.get_node(a);
        b1 = this.get_node(b);
        if (sortType === "asc"){
            return (a1.text > b1.text) ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return (a1.text > b1.text) ? -1 : 1;
        }},
    core: {
      data: [{
        id: "padre1",
        parent: "#",
        text: "Padre 1",
        icon: 'fa fa-star text-warning'
      }, {
        id: "padre2",
        parent: "#",
        text: "Padre 2"
      }, {
        id: "id3",
        parent: "padre1",
        text: "Figlio 1 di padre 1"
      }, {
        id: "id4",
        parent: "padre1",
        text: "Figlio 2 di padre 1"
      }, {
        id: "id5",
        parent: "padre2",
        text: "Figlio 1 di padre 2"
      }, {
        id: "id6",
        parent: "id5",
        text: "Figlio 1 di figlio 1 di padre 2"
      }, {
        id: "id7",
        parent: "id5",
        text: "Figlio 2 di figlio 1 di padre 2"
      }, {
        id: "id8",
        parent: "id5",
        text: "Figlio 3 di figlio 1 di padre 2"
      }, {
        id: "id9",
        parent: "#",
        text: "Figlio 3 di figlio 1 di padre 2"
      }]
    }
  });
});

function contextMenu(node) {
  var items = {};
    items.selezionaTutti = {
      label: 'Seleziona tutti',
      icon: 'fa fa-check-square',
      action: function(questo) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(questo);
      }
    }

    items.asc = {
      "seperator_before": false,
            "seperator_after": false,
            "label": "Ascending",
            action: function (obj) {
                setSortFunction('asc');
                var selector = '#test';

                $(selector).jstree(true).refresh();
            }
    }

     items.desc = {
     "seperator_before": false,
            "seperator_after": false,
            "label": "Descending",
            action: function (obj) {
                setSortFunction('desc');
                var selector = '#test';

                $(selector).jstree(true).refresh();
            }
    }



  return items;
}

function setSortFunction(sort){
 sortType = sort;
}
```